# Unable to Load MNIST dataset in Tensorflow using Jupyter Notebook in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

I encountered some error when loading Mnist datasets in Jupyter Notebook, and i'm using windows.

My python version is 3.7, I installed using microsoft visual studio.
i have anaconda installed.

i tried to run this code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

here is the error message that i get :

```
SSLError: Failed to construct dataset mnistHTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tfds-data/?prefix=dataset_info/mnist/3.0.1/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

​Please help, Thanks before!

Comment: It seems you are behind some corporate firewall proxy, which is blocking your access to download the dataset, as an alternative you can manually download data and read it locally

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response amish, do you know where can i download the data and where to put it in my local?

Comment: I was able to solve error on os X. There are several solutions posted on this link without needing to manually download datasets https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33285

Answer (score 3):

This `load_data` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)  has link to Github repository which provides url to get `mnist.npz` file.

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz

Put it into any local directory:

```
path = '/your local directory path/'
```

Per doc'n mnist is "Tuple of Numpy arrays: (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)"
so you can read it as follows:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path=path + 'mnist.npz'
)
```

And then start using it in model.

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubes with final tensors when tried to load MNIST from mnist.npz. I recommend to download raw `tar.gz` files from [YannLeCun](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) and place them somewhere locally. Method `_get_manually_downloaded_path` from `download_manager.py` (`\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\download`) will tell you where it wants your archives to be

```
manual_path = manual_dir / expected_url_info.filename
if not manual_path.exists():  # File not manually downloaded
    print('LOOKED FOR FILES IN', manual_path) # Added myself
    return None
```

When calling, use this

```
(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
    download=True,
    data_dir='C:\\Users\\Batman\\tensorflow_datasets\\mnist'
)
```

It is the only one solution for MNIST I have found. Other datasets could be downloaded but also support this `manual` hack, tried with `fashion_mnist` with tars from [Github](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist)